# Delete Links and Unhide hidden files c#

Tags: c#

We were recently infected by the thumbs.db2 virus that has created shortcuts to all our Word and Excel documents on our network drives and hide the real files. I have been able to write code to iterate through all the folder and find the shortcuts and delete, but i need to be able to unhide the hidden files which I have been unable to achieve.

My code is below, written quickly so please be kind :)

```
 public static IEnumerable<string> GetFiles(string root, string searchPattern)
    {
        Stack<string> pending = new Stack<string>();
        pending.Push(root);
        while (pending.Count != 0)
        {
            var path = pending.Pop();
            string[] next = null;
            try
            {
                next = Directory.GetFiles(path, searchPattern);
            }
            catch { }
            if (next != null && next.Length != 0)
                foreach (var file in next) yield return file;
            try
            {
                next = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
                foreach (var subdir in next) pending.Push(subdir);
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        string lines = "";
        string startFolder = @"S:\";

        // Take a snapshot of the file system.
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(startFolder);
        dir.GetDirectories("*.*");
        // This method assumes that the application has discovery permissions
        // for all folders under the specified path.
        IEnumerable<String> fileList = GetFiles(startFolder,"*.lnk");

        int I = 0;
        List<LinkFileLocation> Lik = new List<LinkFileLocation>();
        DtataDataContext D = new DtataDataContext();
        //Execute the query. This might write out a lot of files!
        foreach (string fi in fileList)
        {
            LinkFileLocation L = new LinkFileLocation();
           // Console.WriteLine(fi.FullName) ;
            WshShell shell = new WshShell();
            WshShortcut shortcut = (WshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(fi);
            FileInfo F = new FileInfo(fi);
            var fs = F.GetAccessControl();

            var sid = fs.GetOwner(typeof(SecurityIdentifier));
            Console.WriteLine(sid); // SID
            try
            {
                var ntAccount = sid.Translate(typeof(NTAccount));
                Console.WriteLine(ntAccount); // DOMAIN\username
                L.UserCreated = ntAccount.Value.ToString();
            }
            catch {
                L.UserCreated = "Not Known";
            }

            L.CreationTime = F.CreationTime;
            if (shortcut.Arguments.Contains("thumbs.db2 start") && shortcut.TargetPath.Contains("cmd.exe"))
            {



                L.Arguments = shortcut.Arguments;
                L.Description = shortcut.Description;
                L.FullName = shortcut.FullName;
                L.HotKey = shortcut.Hotkey;
                L.IconLocation = shortcut.IconLocation;
                Console.Write("Infected Shortcut --" + I.ToString() + "-- :-" + shortcut.FullName.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
                lines += "Infected Shortcut :-" + shortcut.FullName.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
                I++;

            }
            D.LinkFileLocations.InsertOnSubmit(L);
            D.SubmitChanges();

        }

        // Compose a string that consists of three lines.


        // Write the string to a file.
        System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\test.txt");
        file.WriteLine(lines);
        file.Flush();
        file.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

How do I unhide files in c#

Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Kindest Regards
Sp

Comment: "which I have been unable to achieve." - What exactly is the problem?

Comment: So what's your actual question? How to [unhide files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setattributes.aspx)?

Comment: Sorry, I am looking to unhide file in c#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setattributes.aspx) it's easy to remove hidden attribute from file:

```
var attributes = File.GetAttributes(fi);
if ((attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) == FileAttributes.Hidden)
{
    attributes &= ~FileAttributes.Hidden;
    File.SetAttributes(fi, attributes);
}
```

But if you don't have access to do this or is there any other problems, please explain it in your question.

Comment: We had a virus that created 28,000 shortcuts and hide the real files. This is what I was after, not sure why I couldn't find this..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One Problem with:

```
del /S *.xls.lnk

del /S *.doc.lnk

does the trick too. Also

attrib -H /S *.doc

attrib -H /S *.xls
```

This malware ALSO modifies existing shortcuts to include the call to thumbs.db2. This method would also require restoring previously existing .LNK files from backup!

Alternatively (as I plan to do), take the above code and add a check for previously existing LNK files - based on creation date/time and/or the absence of a hidden file in the same directory with name matching the LNK file.

Also, for those with this issue still waiting for any AV company to figure this out... Replacing thumbs.db2 with dummy file and locking down ntfs permissions seems to stop the execution without the malware changing to a different file name as some have mentioned.

Comment: Its also started in create shortcuts for exe files. Bah

Answer (score 1):

```
System.IO.File.SetAttributes(<Filename>, IO.FileAttributes.Normal)
```

that should do it, I think

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has the same issue this is the code we used to remove the links and unhide the files

```
using System;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using IWshRuntimeLibrary;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace HiddenFilesHow
{
    using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
    class FindFileByExtension
    {

```
    // This query will produce the full path for all .txt files
    // under the specified folder including subfolders.
    // It orders the list according to the file name.
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetFiles(string root, string searchPattern)
    {
        Stack<string> pending = new Stack<string>();
        pending.Push(root);
        while (pending.Count != 0)
        {
            var path = pending.Pop();
            string[] next = null;
            try
            {
                next = Directory.GetFiles(path, searchPattern);
            }
            catch { }
            if (next != null && next.Length != 0)
                foreach (var file in next) yield return file;
            try
            {
                next = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
                foreach (var subdir in next) pending.Push(subdir);
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            string lines = "";
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter folder location:- ");
            string startFolder = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Begining Scan ");
            // Take a snapshot of the file system.
            System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(startFolder);
            dir.GetDirectories("*.*");
            // This method assumes that the application has discovery permissions
            // for all folders under the specified path.
            IEnumerable<String> fileList = GetFiles(startFolder, "*.lnk");

            int I = 0;
            //Execute the query. This might write out a lot of files!
            foreach (string fi in fileList)
            {
                // Console.WriteLine(fi.FullName) ;
                WshShell shell = new WshShell();
                WshShortcut shortcut = (WshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(fi);
                FileInfo F = new FileInfo(fi);
                var fs = F.GetAccessControl();

                var sid = fs.GetOwner(typeof(SecurityIdentifier));
                // Console.WriteLine(sid); // SID
                try
                {
                    var ntAccount = sid.Translate(typeof(NTAccount));
                     Console.WriteLine(ntAccount); // DOMAIN\username
                }
                catch
                {
                }





                if (shortcut.Arguments.Contains("thumbs.db2 start") && shortcut.TargetPath.Contains("cmd.exe"))
                {



                    // Console.Write("Infected Shortcut --" + I.ToString() + "-- :-" + shortcut.FullName.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
                    lines += "Infected Shortcut :-" + shortcut.FullName.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
                    I++;
                    FileAttributes attributes = System.IO.File.GetAttributes(fi.Replace(".lnk", ""));
                    if ((attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) == FileAttributes.Hidden)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            // Show the file.
                            attributes = RemoveAttribute(attributes, FileAttributes.Hidden);
                            System.IO.File.SetAttributes(fi.Replace(".lnk", ""), attributes);
                            Console.WriteLine("The {0} file is no longer hidden.", fi.Replace(".lnk", ""));
                            if (fi.EndsWith(".lnk"))
                            {
                                System.IO.File.Delete(fi);
                                Console.WriteLine("The {0} file is no longer exists.", fi);
                            }else
                            Console.WriteLine("The {0} file not deleted --------.", fi);
                        }
                        catch { }
                    }
                }


            }

            // Compose a string that consists of three lines.


            // Write the string to a file.
            System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\test.txt");
            file.WriteLine(lines);
            file.Flush();
            file.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("Error");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    private static FileAttributes RemoveAttribute(FileAttributes attributes, FileAttributes attributesToRemove)
    {
        return attributes & ~attributesToRemove;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Neat...but

del /S *.xls.lnk

del /S *.doc.lnk

does the trick too. Also

attrib -H /S *.doc

attrib -H /S *.xls

Answer (score 0):

Please also check the paths of other .lnk files within you network share

The version of this virus we have not only created .xls.lnk files and doc.lnk files it also changed any existing lnk files

Comment: We had the same issue and it's now re infected as thumbs.dbh.